# Function mapping notation for a binary operation on a set

Tags: binary-operations

I found the following definition of a binary operation on a set from [here](https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/2633/22/lectures14.pdf):

A binary operation $*$ on a set $S$ is a map $\ast:S\times S \rightarrow S$

My question is, if I define an operation $\ast$, then should it be possible to reach every point in $S$ with some input in $S\times S$? What if I define an operation on a set for which the image was always in $S$, but could never be some parts of $S$?

The notation seems to suggest that this would not classify as a binary operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining such an operation would be fine. It just depends on how useful you want your binary operation to be. A binary operation that reaches every element of the set is an essential part of a mathematical group, which is a very important area of study. But there are objects called semi-groups that may not have this property, and are still useful.

Comment: Great thank you, but what I wanted to ask was would the notation $\ast:S\times S \rightarrow S$ still be valid for such an operation?

Comment: Yes, the function need not be surjective to have that notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly have binary operations on a set where not every element of the set is an output.  For instance, addition on the positive integers is a lovely binary operation on the positive integers, but you can't reach $1$ as an output.